# Issues Arising in windows 7 /Ie8 when running custom Built Activex Control

Tags: web, activex, controls, trusted

Description:

The project deals with interaction with the remote desktop connecting through web browser (Internet Explorer).

What we did:

We have created an activex control that  and installs through the web browser into client machine which lets the user to connect to different servers through web browser.

What is in Activex

In Activex we used an MSTSC.lib file and by passing the relevant parameters to it. It connects to the remote Desktop.

What are the Problems facing now?

We are able to connect to remote desktop but randomly keyboard does not work in remote machine. Where as mouse works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to think that this is either a problem with the ActiveX control you're using or the server you're connecting to.  It doesn't sound like you have a programming issue that's under your control which you can fix.  I would ask whoever provided the ActiveX control connecting to the Remote Desktop for support.

Comment: We have checked the control on different servers. This problem happens only in Ie8 . This problem doesn't show up in IE7. We tried running IE8 in compatability mode , but that didn't solve the issue.

Basically , we need to add our site to the end user's Trusted Site List. We are able to achieve this programatically as of now.